# What is the difference in the vector<int> vec[n] and vector<vector<int>> vec in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, c++14

I just started learning graphs data structure and came through the adjacency matrix and adjacency lists.
The Adjacency list use `vector<int> vec[n]`, where n is the number of vertices.
But I think that the working of `vector<int> vec[n]` i.e so-called adjacency list is same as the vector of vectors...i.e `vector<vector<int>> vec`.
Please help me out with this!

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an array and a `std::vector`? It's the same situation here, except it's "an array of `std::vector`s" and "a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s". Also unless `n` is a constant expression, [one version isn't standard C++ at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 4):

Let's start simple:

```
int arr[n];
std::vector<int> vec;
```

`arr` is a C array of `int`s. This data type is very bare bone. You can't easily get its size and lacks all of the modern OOP features. It has a lot of other problems e.g.:

- in most contexts it decays to pointer
- the return type cannot be array
- you can't have array type as function parameter - what looks like a C array type is in fact a pointer type

`vec` is a proper C++ container representing a dynamic vector. You can access its size, you can grow it, shrink it etc.

Don't use C arrays. Use standard containers. `std::vector` should be the first choice. If the size is known at compile time and it doesn't change use `std::array` instead.

```
vector<int> vec[n]
```

Is a freakish Frankenstein's monster. It's a C array of vectors of `int`s.

> is same as the vector of vectors...i.e `vector<vector<int>> vec`

Close. The C++ equivalent would be `std::array<std::vector<int>, n>`.

---

Note: there are some compilers (most notably gcc and clang) that accept `n` as a non constant size for a C array (the so called Variable Length Arrays), but that isn't standard and portable.

Comment: "If the size doesn't change after initialization" then `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` would be a good option.  For `std::array` the size can't change *ever*, not even at initialization.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see what you mean. I rephrased it.

Answer (score 1):

Both are not equivalent

```
std::vector<int> vec[n];
```

declares an fixed size array of size `n` where `n` must be known at compile time (or a compiler extension must be available). During the initialization of `vec` the constructors of all `n` vectors are called. These vectors are allocated on the stack.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
```

creates an empty vector of vectors though. The constructor of `std::vector<int>` is never called. You need to call

```
vec.resize(n);
```

to change the size of `vec` to `n` calling the constructors of `std::vector<int>` `n` times. In contrast to `std::vector<int> vec[n];` `n` does not need to be a compile time constant with this approach. Furthermore you can apply other operations on a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` changing the number of elements further.

In the second version the `std::vector<int>` objects are allocated on the heap. (The elements of the `std::vector<int>`s are stored different locations on the heap.)

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
std::vector<int> vec[n];
```

there is declared an array. You can not resize the array for example removing or adding new elements.

On the other hand, using this declaration

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec( n );
```

you can resize the vector removing or adding new elements.

Another problem is that arrays do not have the assignment operator.
Also arrays do not have comparison operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> vec[n];
```

- is an array (a so called C-Style array) of size `n` with elements of type `vector<int>`
- `vec` can't grow / shrink in size, however it's elements can (`.resize()`, `.push_back()`, `.pop_back()`)

---

```
vector<vector<int>> vec;
```

- is a two dimensional vector of type `int`
- `vec` can grow / shrink to any size, and it's element can do so as well.

---

which one is better? For your case the `vector<vector<int>>` probably, but it really depends on the use, C-Style arrays require you know the size before, but can be more optimized as the memory will be on the stack. For example, if you know the size of the matrix beforehand, you can use a pure 2d C-Style array:

```
int matrix[n][m];
```

With C-Style arrays you loose the size when passed to a function, so [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is preferred here, they are as optimized and come with utilities such as `.size()`, `.back()` etc:

```
std::array<std::array<int, m>, n> matrix;
```